# Scheme problem (using a function as a parameter)

Tags: scheme

I'm a Scheme newbie and trying to make sense of my homework.
I've a function I made earlier called **duplicate**, and it looks like this:

```
( DEFINE ( duplicate lis )
          (IF (NULL? lis) '())
          ((CONS (CAR lis) (CONS (CAR lis) (duplicate (CDR lis))))
         ))
```

A typical i/o from this would be i: (duplicate '(1 2 3 4)) o: (1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4), so basicly it duplicates everything in the list.
Moving on:
Now I'm supposed to make a function that's called **comp**.
It's supposed to be built like this:

```
(DEFINE (comp f g) (lambda (x) (f (g (x))))
```

Where I could input '(1 2 3 4) and it would return (1 1 4 4 9 9 16 16)

so f = **duplicate** and g = **lambda**.
I know **lambda** should probably look like this:

```
(lambda (x) (* x x))
```

But here's where the problem starts, I've already spent several hours on this, and as you can see not made much progress.

Any help would be appreciated.
Best regards.

Comment: 1. In `comp()`  you can't have `(x)`; `x`is not a function: it should be `(g x)` instead of `(g(x))` 2. To use `comp` with `lambda` , your (lambda(x..)) needs to work on a list to be compatible with `double`; as it is, this `lambda` only works on a single number.  That is hard to do without loop.

Answer (score 2):

Use `map`:

```
> (map (lambda (x) (* x x)) (duplicate '(1 2 3 4)))
=> (1 1 4 4 9 9 16 16)
```

or, modify `duplicate` to take a procedure as its second argument and apply it to each element of the list:

```
(define (duplicate lst p)
  (if (null? lst) ()
      (append (list (p (car lst)) (p (car lst))) (duplicate (cdr lst) p))))

> (duplicate '(1 2 3 4) (lambda (x) (* x x)))
=> (1 1 4 4 9 9 16 16)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way to do is as follows:

```
(define (comp f g) (lambda (x) (f (g x))))
(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (dup x) (list x x))
(define (duplicate-square lst)
  (foldr append '() (map (comp dup square) lst)))
```

Now at the repl, do:

```
> (duplicate-square '(1 2 3 4))
'(1 1 4 4 9 9 16 16)
```